# NullReferenceException in untouched asp.net template (visual studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I'm  trying to learn asp.net and I've created an asp.net project from the templates in visual studio. I used the template MVC with the individual user authentication option. When I run the project, without changing anything, if I click the Login button I get a NullReferenceException from Login.cshtml, line 20.

I've tried to figure it out myself but I couldn't, due to lack of experience; I've also failed to find anything about this issue online.

I appreciate your help.

Also if you're unable to reproduce the error, just ping me and I'll share the source code.

-Edit

Reproduction Steps:

```
> (VS 16.9.3) Create a new project 
> ASP.Net Web Application (.NET Framework)
> .NET Framework = 4.7.2, project template = MVC, Authentication = Individual User Accounts 
> Debug IIS Express (https://localhost:44316) 
> Firefox: Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead, The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. 
> Accept Risk 
> Click "Log in" 
> NullReferenceException thrown at Login.cshtml, line 20
```

Login.cshtml, line 20:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Exception Details:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Comment: Please provide the exact steps to create the project.

Comment: Show the stack trace, provide a [mcve] etc.

Comment: @Llama Added the details

Comment: I've followed your exact steps and I can't reproduce it. I'd suggest recreating the project, or perhaps reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: @Llama can I ask for a favor? Can you send me the solution that you have created? I want experiment if this issue arises from compilation etc. or the template itself. You can send it to efezaladin6@gmail.com

Comment: @JohnG No it does not

Comment: So what is `null` on the line… `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })` … ? Put a break-point on that line of code and see what value is `null`. I would guess it has to be `@Html.TextBoxFor`.

Answer (score 0):

I have run across this issue also. I'm not sure why this happens but I did find a work around.  The LoginViewModel object has a null value when received from the AccountController. Change the AccountController Login Get method to include a new LoginViewModel when calling the view.

```
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }
```

This holds true for the Register method as well except it's expecting a RegisterViewModel.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the issue. The phenomenon I've come across is called the first-chance exception, I don't have an idea how it works or for what it is used, but these exceptions don't interfere with the program flow, I was able to just skip them. In order not having to manually skip each time such exception is thrown I just disabled the exception.

To be honest I don't know a word about this topic so I'm likely not 100% correct. If you know more about this I would still appreciate your knowledge.

Further reading: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23649#issuecomment-662098484
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: _”I just disabled the exception.”_ … you will regret this at some time in the near future.